# List View - User not able create

Tags: list-view

We have created 2 users with same profile and role.
 but facing issues when creating list view.

Profile has permission 'Create and customize view'
One user is able to create list view and other is not. what could be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure they both share the same profile? Do they both have **read access** to the object in question?

Comment: I think this should be impossible too. Maybe try to check again the profile assignment. If they have the same... they should both create the same list view.

Comment: Got it.. 1st user had an permission set where customize application permission was given. But other user was not assigned this pemission set.